# 「"」の文字を置換する方法

Tags: python

input関数を使ってパスを使ってそこからファイルを開こうと思っているのですが、Windowsのエクスプローラにあるパスのコピーで「"」が前後に入力されてしまい、それをinputが文字列として格納するので、`b'"path"'`となって二重になってしまいます。
発生するエラーは以下になります。ちなみにファイルはちゃんと存在しています。

> File b'"E:\Programming\Python\Matplotlib\Geochemi_test3.csv"' does
>   not exist

これを回避しようと思い置換しようと思ったのですが、どうも認識しないようです。
入力時にわざわざ前後の「"」を削除するのも手間です。
良い回避方法などありませんか？よろしくお願いいたします。

例↓

```
input1=input("パスのコピーを取って貼り付けてください\n>>>")
input1.replace("\"","")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

python3.xではわざわざ前後の「"」を削除しないと目的は達成できないはずです。

```
input1 = input("パスのコピーを取って貼り付けてください\n>>>").strip('"')
print(input1)
```

python2.xには[`raw_input`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915366)という関数がありまして、`input`を直接`eval`で関数として評価することで副次的に前後のクォーテーションを削除できます。
python3.xでは`eval(input())`で同様の動作を実現できますが、意図しない結果になる上にインジェクション攻撃にも使われかねないので推奨できません。

```
input1 = eval(input(r'input "C:\hoge">>>'))
print(input1)
#C:\hoge

input2 = eval(input('input 1+2>>>'))
print(input2)
#3
```

[3.x input](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#input)
[2.x raw_input](https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ユーザー視点で考えたら手間かなと思い、パスのコピーからを考えておりましたが、安全面を考えて別の方法を探ってみます！

Comment: tkinterのGUIから選択する方法が良さそうなので、そちらでやってみようと思います。